# InvalidOperationException: active Input handling conflict

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a medical application on immersive visualization using Oculus Quest 2. I am trying to integrate both XR interaction manager (XR rig) for navigation into my 3D model and as well as keyboard controls because in my company some clients prefer using keyboard navigation. But when I implement it, I get the following error.

```
InvalidOperationException: You are trying to read Input using the UnityEngine.Input class, but you have switched active Input handling to Input System package in Player Settings. mouseLook.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/FPP/mouseLook.cs:19)
```

I understand that there is a conflict with my **mouseLook.cs** script with the active Input handling. But I do not know how can I implement both keyboard controls and Oculus hand controls so that the users can choose according to their preference. Thanks for any input.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`[unityscript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a custom JavaScript flavor-like language used in early Unity versions and is **long deprecated** by now. Your code is of course in `c#`

Answer (score 0):

Unity has two different input systems. Your project is set to use the new one.
To fix this issue, go to player settings and change active input handling to both.
Or better, modify the problem script to use the new input system.

Comment: I tried **both** but no success.

Comment: Did the error message change or have no impact?